# Java Confusion-- Someone Translate?

Tags: javascript, html, elementor

I’m currently taking an online class and I need to explain what this short piece of code means. Obviously, some of it represents days, hours, minutes, and seconds but the values don’t seem to make sense. Why would someone release an item in 15 days, 18 hours, 2928 minutes, and 00 seconds? Am I misinterpreting this?

```
<div class="elementor-countdown-wrapper" data-date="1518292800">
<div class="elementor-countdown-item"><span class="elementor-countdown-digits 
   elementor-countdown-days"></span> <span class="elementor-countdown- 
    label">Days</span></div>
<div class="elementor-countdown-item"><span class="elementor-countdown-digits 
    elementor-countdown-hours"></span> <span class="elementor-countdown- 
    label">Hours</span></div>
<div class="elementor-countdown-item"><span class="elementor-countdown-digits 
     elementor-countdown-minutes"></span> <span class="elementor-countdown- 
     label">Minutes</span></div>
<div class="elementor-countdown-item"><span class="elementor-countdown-digits 
    elementor-countdown-seconds"></span> <span class="elementor-countdown- 
    label">Seconds</span></div>
```

Comment: What makes you think that the value is interpreted like that? Do you refer to some specification?

Comment: Javascript is not Java. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you're looking at, is [seconds from epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). It is not a duration, but actually a date. In JavaScript, you may convert this value to *milliseconds from epoch*, and construct a date object out of it.

See the following snippet:

```js
var secondsFromEpoch = 1518292800;
var millisFromEpoch = secondsFromEpoch * 1000;
var date = new Date(millisFromEpoch);

console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

So, this value represents the date Feb 11, 2018, and time 1:30am.